# attachment_fu image resizing with s3 storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, attachment-fu

I'm facing a problem right now, where in my company, we want to resize the thumbnail images we have on amazon s3 storage using attachment_fu, I've been investigating how to regenerate this thumbnails and had found some guidelines to do it, however all of them work with local storage.

I've found a way, that involves more or less downloading the image from S3 using RestClient, and then assigning each downloaded image to each photo instance as a new attachment, I don't know if this is the best way (slow, expensive?), I would like to know if someone out there have had the same situation, did you do more or less the same? or did you find a more elegant way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [TntDrive](http://tntdrive.com) to mount your Amazon S3 Bucket as a windows Drive. Then you can work with your images just like they are on a local storage.